# jquery: addclass to parent when its child is selected

Tags: jquery, parent-child, addclass

http://jsfiddle.net/DfcdQ/

```
<ol id="nav">
<li><a href="a.php" class="selected">A</a>
  <ol class="child">
  <li><a href="a-1.php">A-1</a></li>
  </ol>
</li>
<li><a href="b.php">B</a>
  <ol class="child">
  <li><a href="b-1.php">B-1</a></li>
  <li><a href="b-2.php">B-2</a></li>
  </ol>
</li>
<li><a href="c.php">C</a>
  <ol class="child">
  <li><a href="c-1.php">c-1</a></li>
  <li><a href="c-2.php">c-2</a></li>
  <li><a href="c-3.php">c-3</a></li>
  <li><a href="c-4.php">c-4</a></li>
  </ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

When child menu selected, its parent menu is selected, too.
The code below works on child css but not parent's.

```
var loc = 'c-3.php';

$("#nav a").each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("selected");
  if (loc.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1) {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); /* <=== doesn't work :( */
  }
});
```

This one doesn't work either...

```
$(this).closest('ol').parent().addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are confusing about the parents, this works:http://jsfiddle.net/DfcdQ/7/

```
var loc = 'c-3.php';

$("#nav a").each(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("selected");
   if (loc.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1) {
       $(this).addClass("selected");
       $(this).parent().parent().siblings(':first').addClass("selected");
   }
});​
```

`$(this).parent()` refers to the `<li><a href="c-3.php">c-3</a></li>`, it is not refereing to the `<a href="c.php">C</a>`

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! And thank you for explaining about the parent().. :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with bingjie2680 but depends on whether you wanted the c.php anchor to have the selected class(bingjie2680 solution) or the li surrounding all the items (below).

$(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("selected");

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work..

$(this).parent() => <li><a href="c-3.php">c-3</a></li>
$(this).parent().parent() => <ol><li><a href="c-3.php">c-3</a></li></ol>
$(this).parent().parent().parent() => ???

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().parent() => <li><a href="c.php">C</a><ol class="child"><li><a href="c-1.php">c-1</a></li><li><a href="c-2.php">c-2</a></li><li><a href="c-3.php">c-3</a></li><li><a href="c-4.php">c-4</a></li><li></ol></li> 

The whole list item, but I get that you wanted the anchor.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/aS28N/ for result. I added css rule #nav li.selected { background:#ccc }

Answer (score 0):

I've modified based on closest.

```
$(this).closest('ol').parent('li').find('a').addClass("selected");
```

Here is the working fiddel link http://jsfiddle.net/DfcdQ/12/

Comment: Thank you, but it also affects the other sibling menues.

Comment: How it affects to other sibling menus?